# Sonar cube not showing the test coverage percentage for Java project properly

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have a spring-based java project and I have my tests placed in /src/test/java folder. I tried to run the Sonar cube locally via

docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube

in order to analyze the percentage of the test coverage. The test coverage shows 0% even though I have many tests in my project. And the Number of Unit tests count shows as 8 though there are more than that. Here is the screenshot

[image]

And here is my general Settings
[image]

Does anyone has any idea how to configure Sonar cube to reflect the test coverage?

Comment: Which code coverage tool are you using ?

Comment: I am using Sonar cube

Comment: Sonarqube is analysis tool. I am talking about code-coverage tool like jacoco, clover etc. You can read more here - https://dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-tools-comparison

Comment: I was not aware of JaCoCo. I was under the assumption that Sonar cube would do the magic. I do not know how to configure JaCoCO. I want to know how to configure it and see the results. could you give some information regarding that?

Comment: You can follow this link and try to configure jacoco for code coverage - https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/ This link has configuration with maven...but if you use other that this like ant or gradle you can easily find their configuration on google.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation when trying to use Sonar with Docker.

What worked for me was:

1. Make sure you have run your tests [You can use mvn test]
2. Make sure JaCoCo has generated the coverage report [In my case reports were generated in folder target\jacoco-report]
3. Set the following property pointing to your XML report

[Sonar property to be set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP2wY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube and sonar scanner do not provide tooling to generate code coverage reports. This should be done with tools like jacoco for java or opencover for .NET.

You can then add the output of jacoco to the sonar scanner with the `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` property.

so you will basically need the following steps for your analysis:

1. Sonar scanner begin
2. Restore packages
3. Build application
4. Use code coverage tool to test and calculate the coverage for your app
5. Sonar scanner end